# Streams Optional<Question> find highest scoring Question with

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream, option-type

/Hi everyone! I am really struggeling with this methode. I have to find out the question with the highest score and have to filter it with *minimumviews*.

```
public Stream<Question> stream() {
    Stream<Question> questionStream = Arrays.stream(items);
    questionStream.forEach(System.out::println);
    return questionStream;
}

public Optional<Question> findHighestScoringQuestionWith(int minimumViews){

    return stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Question::getScore))
        .filter(x -> x.getViewCount() >= minimumViews)
        .findFirst();        
}
```

//I would be very grateful if someone can help me with this issue. I thank you all in advance.

//My exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.<init>(AbstractPipeline.java:203)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:94)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$StatefulOp.<init>(ReferencePipeline.java:725)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$OfRef.<init>(SortedOps.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps.makeRef(SortedOps.java:63)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.sorted(ReferencePipeline.java:463)
at stackoverflow.Data.sortedStream(Data.java:156)
at stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Comment: Your `stream()` method is returning a stream that's already been used.

Comment: Show us your `stream()` method.

Comment: However, `stream().filter(x -> x.getViewCount() >= minimumViews).min(Comparator.comparing(Question::getScore))` is a better way to do this: you don't need to sort to find the minimum

Comment: Also: "I have to find out the question with the highest score" you're currently finding the question with the lower score (and sufficient views).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn public Stream<Question> stream() {
        Stream<Question> questionStream = Arrays.stream(items);
        questionStream.forEach(System.out::println);
        return questionStream;
    }

Comment: @AndyTurner public Stream<Question> stream() {
        Stream<Question> questionStream = Arrays.stream(items);
        questionStream.forEach(System.out::println);
        return questionStream;
    }

Comment: @huettl, please edit your question and put that code snippet in there.

Answer (score 3):

> Stream operations are divided into *intermediate* and *terminal* operations, and are combined to form *stream pipelines*. A stream pipeline consists of a source (such as a `Collection`, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more intermediate operations such as `Stream.filter` or `Stream.map`; and a terminal operation such as `Stream.forEach` or `Stream.reduce`.

- [*Package Summary for* `java.util.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

`Stream.forEach` is a *terminal* operation, meaning that it completes a *stream pipeline*. The whole *stream pipeline* is evaluated when a *terminal* operation is invoked, it has been **operated upon**, as stated in the exception.

If you want to have multiple *terminal* operations, you need to set up multiple *stream pipelines*.

To perform some operation on the data mid stream, you can use `Stream.peek`:

```
public Stream<Question> stream() {
    Stream<Question> questionStream = Arrays.stream(items);                    
    return questionStream.peek(System.out::println);         // <-
}

public Optional<Question> findHighestScoringQuestionWith(int minimumViews){
    return stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Question::getScore))
        .filter(x -> x.getViewCount() >= minimumViews)
        .findFirst();      
}
```

This will print out all items in the stream, **but only once a terminal operation is called** and the stream is evaluated. In your case, that terminal operation is `Stream.findFirst` in the `findHighestScoringQuestionWith` method.

Answer (score 0):

Streams are one-shot objects, you can't use them more than once.

The problem is that you are calling `questionStream.forEach` in the stream() method, so it is already used up before you return.  If you really want to print out the contents, then you could do `Arrays.asList(items).forEach(System.out::println);`